# How to calculate orginal amount?

Tags: arithmetic

It might be simple question for people over here...

I just get the bank statment where I get 41000 bucks, 
But they mentioned that they cut 2% from orignal amount...
(means i get the 41000 after cutting 2%)

Now, I am not able to calculate orginal amount , how to calculate the orignal amt ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have some **unknown fixed number** called *the original amount*: call that number x.

From that number x, 2% of that number or 2% of x was taken away so x - (2%)x = $41,000.

Solving for x gives: x = $41,836.73

Answer (score 1):

The setup is correct, and helped me remember how to set up the equation, but it helps to show the steps between equation and answer too:

x-(2%)x = 41000

100%x-2%x = 41000

98%x = 41000

0.98x/0.98=41000/0.98

x = 41836.73

Check backwards 41836.73 * .02 = 836.73 (ish)

418363.73-836.73 = 41000